# sails.js and multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have been playing with node.js and more recently sails.js. In node.js I was using express and so it was easy to define multiple paramters by using Routers.get however I am struggling in sails.

I have created a api using the built in command and noticed that this will take one param that defaults to a name of id, this is fine if I just wish to use the one param but I am trying to call a function that fires a stored procedure that requires 4 params. These are being called via an Android device.

Using node I was sending something like

```
myserveraddress/sendgrn/" + 1 + "/" + User + "/" + 1111 + "/" + 22)
```

This doesn;t work in sails, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How did you define your routes in sails ? Did you only used the api generator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used the default create method and added my params like:

/myserver/myroute/create?param1=1&param2=2 etc

Answer (score 4):

In your config/route.js you could also have manually defined a route like this :

```
'POST /sendgrn/:param1/:param2/:param3/:param4' : "SomeController.sendgrn"
```

And then to get your params in your controller method for instance :

```
sendgrn: function(req, res){
    var p1 = req.param("param1");
    var p2 = req.param("param2");
    ... 
    // do something with the params
}
```

More about routes syntax in sails : [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Routes/RouteTargetSyntax.html)